# Most efficient way of getting bar chart with percentage labels with ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I have a question that is more directed towards what's the most efficient way in order to create a bar chart with percentage labels and the intended layout. I have a data frame containing several columns which includes the column "economy". That column does have the five values "Very good", "Good", "Bad", "Very bad" and "Don't know". Here is the reproducible data:

```
structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 2L), .Label = c("Very good", "Good", "Bad", "Very bad", 
"Don't know"), class = "factor")
```

I used this code with the desired outcome:

```
lebanon %>%
  filter(!is.na(economy), economy != "Don't know") %>%
  count(economy) %>%
  mutate(prop = n / sum(n)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(economy, y = prop, fill = economy)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("darkgreen", "green4", "red3", "red4")) +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent) +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(prop, suffix = "")),
            position=position_dodge(width=0.9), vjust=-0.5, size = 5) +
  labs(x = "", y = "", fill = "") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 15),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 15),
        legend.text = element_text(size = 15))
```

Getting this plot:

[image]

I'm wondering know if this is the most efficient way in order to recalculate the counts to percentage with the desired layout. I used the count function and mutate, but I also know that there might be other ways of handling this problem with stat(prop) and ..count.. function. The problem is that when I use stat(prop) or fill = "prop", it doesn't take the scale_fill_manual function.

[image]

So my question is what's the most efficient way to get my desired bar chart (the one above) without too many intermediate steps for the calculation of percentages. Sorry in advance if my question is not clearly formulated. :)

Greetings

Comment: Your example is not reproducible.  You provide a `factor`, not a `data.frame` and the `factor` does not contain any observations with value "Very good", yet your graph does.

Comment: Probably because there are only few observations with that value in a dataset of 2400 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution. I used your sample of data. I hope this can help:

```
library (ggplot2)
library(scales)

lebanon %>%
  filter(!is.na(economy), economy != "Don't know") %>%
  ggplot(aes(x= economy)) + 
  geom_bar(aes(y = (..count..)/sum(..count..), fill = economy), stat="count") +
  geom_text(aes( label = scales::percent((..count..)/sum(..count..)),
                 y= (..count..)/sum(..count..) ), stat= "count", vjust = -.5) +
  labs(y = "Percent", fill="Economy") +
  scale_y_continuous(labels = scales::percent)
```

[image]

I also found this package that could help you: http://larmarange.github.io/JLutils/reference/stat_fill_labels.html

Comment: Just for information, `stat_fill_labels()` is deprecated. A better and more general implementation called `stat_prop()` is now available on CRAN in `GGally` package.

More information on http://ggobi.github.io/ggally/articles/ggally_stats.html#stat-prop-

Answer (score 1):

The new statistic `stat_prop()` available in GGally was designed for computing proportion easily. More details on http://ggobi.github.io/ggally/articles/ggally_stats.html#stat-prop-

The `by` aesthetic indicates the denominator. Here `by = 1` because you want % of the total.

If you add a facet, all proportions will be computed separately per facet.

In your case you could try something like

```
library(ggplot2)
library(GGally)

ggplot(lebanon) +
  aes(x = economy, y = after_stat(prop), fill = economy, by = 1) +
  geom_bar(stat = "prop") +
  geom_text(aes(label = scales::percent(after_stat(prop))), stat = "prop", vjust=-0.5)
```

[image]